# React data overridden in Data Table after filtering data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, apollo-client, react-tsx, react-data-table-component

**React Data overridden in Data table after filtering data**
Tech stack used: React typescript and GraphQL (apollo client).

- We have used react-data-table-component, mui/material. In this both modules data is overridden after data is filtered.
- Not getting any solution for this issue,
  If anyone can help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Above issue is resolved by the below given code (React typescript):**

```
 const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions = {
        watchQuery: {
            fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
            errorPolicy: 'all',
        },
        query: {
            fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
            errorPolicy: 'all',
        },
        mutate: {
            errorPolicy: 'all',
        },
    };

    return new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://example/graphql',
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        defaultOptions: defaultOptions
    })
```